# how to get multiple rows from a table using SLIM framework

Tags: php, pdo

this is my select command

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id,task FROM tbl_all_task WHERE status = 0");

(there are multiple rows having status ).

i tried $stmt->fetchall() , $stmt->fetchall() etc. Nothing works.

I need all rows so that i could make a JSON ARRAY and return this to mu function call.

Comment: Slim does not have any code related to databases. You are probably using PDO or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you use **[prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)**, you get a chance to make a 'prepared statement',
and bind values to your query (see **[bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)**):

> Many of the more mature databases support the concept of prepared statements. What are they? They can be thought of as a kind of compiled template for the SQL that an application wants to run, that can be customized using variable parameters.

after you prepare and (optionally) bind, you must **[execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)**;
after which, if every thing went right, you can use fetching methods such as **[fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)**.

try it like this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id,task FROM tbl_all_task WHERE status = 0");
$stmt->execute();
if ($data = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
    print_r(json_encode($data));
}
```

if you're not interested in a prepared statement (altough it is generally the prefered way), you can just use the **[query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)** method directly:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->query("SELECT id,task FROM tbl_all_task WHERE status = 0");
if ($data = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
    print_r(json_encode($data));
}
```